# Ember Route Nesting Structure

Tags: ember.js

I’m doing a flash card app where card sets are shown in the left sidebar.  Clicking on a set shows in the main panel:

1. a button bar
2. a table of cards.

On clicking the Study button (link) in the button bar, I would like a study panel to replace the card table.

I’ve tried various ways of doing this such as nesting study under sets or set, but neither works.  Currently nested under set, the problems are:

1. can’t get the study link to populate with the set id.  Perhaps b/c button bar in a partial not an outlet?
2. you can click the link even w/out the id (and i tried a hard-coded one for testing), but displays the set table not the study page.

Relevant code below.  Full code on [github](https://github.com/kagemusha/crambear), and can be viewed on [heroku](http://crambear.herokuapp.com/).

Appreciate help on how best to set this up.

**routing**

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'sets', ->
    @resource 'set', { path: ':set_id' }, ->
      @route 'study', { path: 'study' }, ->


App.SetsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.Set.find()

App.SetRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'content', model

App.SetStudyRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->  App.Set.find(params?.set_id)
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'content', model
```

**sets.hbs**

```
<div id="sets" class="span2">
  <div class="well well-small sidebar-nav-fixed">
      {{partial "sets/set_list"}}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="span9">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

**set.hbs**

```
{{partial "sets/set_actions"}}
<h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{name}}&nbsp;(id: {{id}})</h3>
{{render "cards/table" cards}}
```

**sets/_set_action**

```
{{#linkTo set.study set class="btn btn-primary"}}Study!{{/linkTo}}
<button class="btn btn-primary" {{action addCard}}>Add Card</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" {{action delete}}>Delete Set</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out study link in set_actions has to reference controller (which refers to the set object).  So:

```
{{#linkTo sets.study controller class="btn btn-primary"}}Study!{{/linkTo}}.
```

After that, as long as routes etc specified correctly, seems to work.  Will update the full solution on git.